# External monitoring flickering with Dell XPS 13 9350 laptop

Tags: 16.04, external-monitor, xps, usb-c

I'm using a Dell XPS 13 9350 with Ubuntu 16.04. I've tried three different monitors connected to the USB-C connection on my laptop and they've all had this flickering issue. Sometimes my external monitor won't flicker for hours and sometimes it flickers and resets every minute or two. When I lower my wifi power with the following command, the issue goes away, but I have to reset my wifi every time my laptop resumes from suspend.

```
sudo iwconfig wlp58s0 txpower 15
```

I did not have this issue when using the same laptop with Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The command `sudo iwconfig wlp58s0 txpower 15` can be made to happen automatically by doing the following (I think `wlp58s0` may vary from person to person, but the solution remains the same):

1. Create a script:

`sudo vim /etc/network/if-up/power_adjust`

2. Paste in the following:

`#!/bin/sh
iwconfig "$IFACE" txpower 15`

3. Once the file has been saved, make it executable:

`sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/power_adjust`

Source: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-wireless-networking-41/where-should-i-add-iwconfig-options-to-make-them-permanent-786904/

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that have helped me with this:

- If your router has a 5GHz option, switch permanently to the 5GHz one.
- If you can only do 2.4GHz, disable the switching of channel width between 20 and 40 MHz (force 20)
- If you can, disable IPv6 for your connection.

For me, I had to buy a new router anyway, so I got one with 5GHz and switched to it, which has made most of the problem go away.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same computer, dual boot with Windows 10, and was experiencing the same issue on both operating systems. The display worked perfectly when networking was disabled, but turned off like a light switch when networking was enabled. I ultimately solved the problem by purchasing a USB wireless dongle (Edimax EW-7811Un) and turned off the internal wireless card. It was pretty much plug and play on Windows. On Ubuntu 17.04, I had to blacklist the internal wireless card. No problems since.